# Assigned expression type "X" is not assignable to type "X" | "Y"

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

I'm getting this error from an Angular template:

> Assigned expression type "default" is not assignable to type "default" | "delete" | "rename"`

On a line that says `currentAction = 'default'`:

[image]

But my `currentAction` variable is declared like this:

```
type Action = 'default' | 'delete' | 'rename';
public currentAction: Action = 'default';
```

So I think assigning it is valid as `default` is a valid value.

If I do something similar in the class of my component (not the template), there is no warning nor error:

```
this.currentAction = 'default'
```

Does this look like a bug with my IDE (WebStorm) or there is something wrong with assigning that variable in an Angular template?

Comment: Might be, check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-utvaaa) working fine

Comment: I feel it is the bug from WebStorm, otherwise union types can be used in html as well. Better you can call a method on click and assign it there. Why to take risk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in the IDE, fixed in upcoming 2019.2.
Please try [2019.2 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/eap/) - it seems to work fine there:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

The behavior is correct enough, because the type can be changed and that is why IDE cannot be sure that string value `'default'` will suit to the type in future.

It is better to use [enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) in such cases, because you can use value and change it without any problems:

```
enum Action {
    DEFAULT = 'default',
    DELETE = 'delete',
    RENAME = 'rename'
}
```

Comment: The IDE should not care about what you will change in the future, but about what’s correct _now_.